# Pretty faces + primefaces upload doesn't work

Tags: java, primefaces, jsf-2, prettyfaces

I have a jsf web application. I use primefaces ver. 5.3 and pretty-faces ver. 3.3.3

I have a page, catalogue.xhtml, where there is a file uploader in primefaces:

```
<p:fileUpload onstart="start()" oncomplete="stop()" id="image" styleClass="#{!catalogueBean.form.headerInsert ? '' : 'hidden'}" auto="true"
                            fileUploadListener="#{catalogueBean.imageLoad}" mode="advanced" skinSimple="true" sizeLimit="10000000" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"
                            update="imageOnline" />
```

My CatalogueBean:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
@BeanPage(name = "/admin/catalogue")
public class CatalogueBean {
....
}
```

My pretty-config:

```
  <pretty-config xmlns="http://ocpsoft.org/schema/rewrite-config-prettyfaces"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://ocpsoft.org/schema/rewrite-config-prettyfaces
                      http://ocpsoft.org/xml/ns/prettyfaces/rewrite-config-prettyfaces.xsd">

    ....

    <url-mapping id="adminCatalogue">
        <pattern value="/admin/catalogue" />
        <view-id value="/page/admin/catalogue.xhtml" />
    </url-mapping>

    ....

  </pretty-config>
```

When I upload the file, I got no error, and the image is not uploaded.

I saw already other discussion, but them didn't solve my problem.

In particular I tried to add in my web.xml

```
 <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
 <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
```

where I declare PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

EDIT:

If I change the annotation in class CatalogueBean :

```
@BeanPage(name = "/page/admin/catalogue.xhtml")
```

in the console, after the upload, I see admin/catalog and I don't understand why...

Please let me know what I wrong, and if it's possible to map, for id = adminCatalogue, only calls in GET

Thanks

Comment: PrettyFaces 3.3.3 is extremely old. You should really update to a more recent version.

Comment: and the problem will be solved? I don't think so...

Comment: It is worth a try.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't see an update version. I use maven dependency and the last version availble, is 3.3.3
Have you seen an other version maybe? Thanks

Comment: PrettyFaces is now part of the Rewrite framework. See: https://github.com/ocpsoft/rewrite/blob/master/documentation/src/main/asciidoc/migration/prettyfaces3.asciidoc

Comment: Ok I will see the Rewrite framework. Thanks for suggestion!